# Theorem-Lemma-Proof environment

Tags: hyperref, theorems, cleveref, newtheorem

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath} 

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem*{theorem}{Theorem:}

\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma:}

\newenvironment{proof}{\paragraph{\ Proof:}}{\hfill$\square$}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma} Here is the statement of the lemma.\label{lemma}
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}Here is the statement of the theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}This is the proof of the theorem using \Cref{lemma}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Though I have not numbered the lemma using `\newtheorem*` while referring to the lemma in the proof of the theorem, `Lemma 1` comes up. I want to see `Lemma`, no numbering after that.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: That is not the normal way to define a proof via `ntheorem`, you'd normally use `\theoremstyle{empty}` and then define it as a theorem like the others `\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}` onto which the normal `ntheorem` stylings then apply.

Comment: Also note that `\newheorem*` does not do what you think in `ntheorem`. Why are you even using `ntheorem` with the settings you show in this example it sounds more like you are looking for amsthm` in which `\newtheorem*` does what you think and the `proof` env is already defined for you.

Comment: @daleif I have made changes following your comment. Only the last problem left. Thanks.

Comment: Note again that this `proof` env you provide is broken, the tombstore is not always at the right edge. I cannot help you with `cleveref` as I personnally never use it. Again you are problably better of using `amsthm` (note that my suggestion for `proof` with `ntheorem` above was missing the `thmmarks` option for `ntheorem`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I am not sure why you want to use `cleveref` with this. If you are only using the no-number style then you are probably using the environment only once. And so there's really no need to automatically "detect" reference types! But since you asked for it, here it is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath} 

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}   % note 1
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}           % note 2
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\color{lightgray}\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\Crefformat{lemma}{#2Lemma#3}   % note 3
\crefformat{lemma}{#2lemma#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma} Here is the statement of the lemma.\label{lemma}
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}Here is the statement of the theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}This is the proof of the theorem using \Cref{lemma}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

1. Instead of using `\newtheorem*`, since you are going to need to define the proof environment anyway, and it looks like you are using more or less the same style for all of them, I specified the `nonumberplain` style.
2. Instead of coding the colon in the theorem name, it is better to use the `\theoremseparator` to specify it.
3. This is a difference between `ntheorem` and `amsthm`. In the latter, theorems created using `\newtheorem*` get no reference counter, and so cannot be cross referenced. With `ntheorem` the counter is still there, just suppressed from display. `cleveref` however does not detect the theorem style at all (in fact, it cares not what the style is). So you have to do it yourself by defining a corresponding `\Crefformat` and `\crefformat`. See section 8.2.1 of the `cleveref` manual for details on how this works.

Comment: Just in case: in the unlikely case that you don't care about the hyperlinks produced (in which case I doubly don't understand why you'd be using `cleveref`), you can just use `\namecref` and `\nameCref` to suppress the number.